# Wordpress add_image_size cropping position bug, feature?

Tags: wordpress

I wanted to introduce 3 different version of post thumbnails - each with different cropping (top, center, left) , so i added them like this:

```
add_image_size( 'newscentered', 400, 400, array( 'center', 'center') );
add_image_size( 'newstop', 400, 400, array( 'center', 'top' ) );
add_image_size( 'newsbottom', 400, 400, array( 'center', 'bottom' ) );
```

Now, whenever i use the the_post_thumbnail() with the name of my custom image size i always get the same image - cropped to the default wordpress crop position of ('center', 'center') .

Why is that happening? I did 'refresh' the thumbnails and tried also uploading fresh image files and still i can't get 3 differently cropped versions of the image.

I noticed that when i set the cropping defaults using the following function:

```
set_post_thumbnail_size( 400, 400, array('center', 'bottom'));
```

then it  affects the cropping but for all my thumbnails, so i can only get one "crop position" for all my images.

Guys, is this some kind of bug or do i configure something in a wrong way?

Edit: I'm using the newest official Wordpress version

Greg

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that this is actually a bug, the unique filenames are just not created and one file is being overwritten by another file.

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/40370#comment:2

Comment: I ran into what sounds like a similar (maddening) issue in which my images were being cropped from the *left* instead of *center* as desired, despite my having `add_image_size( 'square-crop-medium', 300, 300, array( 'center', 'center' ) );` defined in functions. After some time, I realized that I needed to create a new image size definition, i.e. with a different name, and that worked, as I had edited my existing definition and the changes didn't "take" so to speak. Apparently, once an image size is first loaded in functions, I guess it can't be modified without creating an entirely new one?